After card declined, javascript seems to stop running on the page Laravel Cashier
I'm adding memberships to our web app, and was testing different cards to be able to handle errors. I noticed that after getting the error declined response from stripe using one of their test cards (generic decline test card for example), I cannot re-submit the form where they card info is, it seems JS stops running as it doesn't even trigger the click event on the button element anymore.
Relevant code below:
Blade file where the payment element is being loaded into:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  @include('layouts.redesign.head')
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <style>
    #overlay {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 100;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: none;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    }

    .cv-spinner {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .spinner {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border: 4px #ddd solid;
      border-top: 4px #2e93e6 solid;
      border-radius: 50%;
      animation: sp-anime 0.8s infinite linear;
    }

    @keyframes sp-anime {
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    .is-hide {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="mad-body--scheme-brown">

<div id="mad-page-wrapper" class="mad-page-wrapper">

  @include('layouts.redesign.header')

  <!--================ Page Title ================-->
  <div class="mad-breadcrumb with-bg-img with-overlay light bg-alignright"
       data-bg-image-src="{{asset('/images/banner-service-consultations.jpg')}}">
    <div class="container wide">
      <h1 class="mad-page-title">Sign up</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container my-3">
    <form method="GET" id="signupForm" class="mad-contact-form mad-form type-2 item-col-1 m-auto"
          style="max-width: 500px">
      <div class="mad-form-item">
        <label for="email">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required placeholder="Name"/>
      </div>
      <div class="mad-form-item">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email"/>
      </div>
      <div class="mad-form-item">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required placeholder="Password"/>
      </div>
      <div class="mad-form-item">
        <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" required
               placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
      </div>
      <div class="mad-col full-width">

        <div class="mad-row full-width row">
          <span id="errors"></span>
          <div class="mad-form-item align-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-big g-recaptcha create_user"
            >{{__('contact_form.submit')}}
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </form>
    <div class="stripe_lmnts mad-contact-form mad-form type-2 item-col-1 m-auto"
         style="display: none; max-width: 500px">
      <!-- Stripe Elements Placeholder -->
      <div id="payment-element"></div>
      <button id="card-button" class="btn btn-primary py-3" data-secret="{{$client_secret}}">
        Sign up
      </button>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div id="overlay">
    <div class="cv-spinner">
      <span class="spinner"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      let user_id;
      $('.create_user').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{route('create_user')}}',
          type: 'GET',
          data: {
            name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
            email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
            password: $('input[name="password"]').val(),
            password_confirmation: $('input[name="password_confirmation"]').val(),
          },
          success: function (data) {
            let response = JSON.parse(data)
            if (!response.error) {
              user_id = response.user_id
              $('.stripe_lmnts').css('display', 'block')
              $('#signupForm').css('display', 'none')
            } else {
              $('#errors').html(response.message)
              if (response.for === 'email') {
                $('input[name="email"]').css('border-color', '#dc3545')
              }
              if (response.for === 'password') {
                $('input[name="password"]').css('border-color', '#dc3545')
                $('input[name="password_confirmation"]').css('border-color', '#dc3545')
              }
            }
          }
        })
      })

      const stripe = Stripe('{{env('STRIPE_KEY')}}');
      const cardButton = $('#card-button');
      const clientSecret = cardButton.data('secret');
      const options = {layout: 'accordion', /* options */};
      const appearance = {
        theme: 'flat',
        variables: {colorPrimaryText: '#262626'}
      };
      const elements = stripe.elements({clientSecret, appearance});
      const paymentElement = elements.create('payment', options);
      paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');


      cardButton.on('click', function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true)
        $(this).addClass('btn-secondary')
        $(this).removeClass('btn-primary')
        $("#overlay").fadeIn(300);
        stripe.confirmSetup({
          elements,
          confirmParams: {
            // Return URL where the customer should be redirected after the PaymentIntent is confirmed.
            return_url: `http://localhost:8080/create-subscription?user_id=${user_id}`,
          },
        })
          .then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
              $(this).prop('disabled', false)
              $(this).removeClass('btn-secondary')
              $(this).addClass('btn-primary')
              $("#overlay").fadeOut(300);
            }
          });
      })


    })
  </script>


</div>

@include('layouts.redesign.footer')

</body>
</html>



I would recommend you focus on debugging the error-handling then block after confirmSetup:
      .then(function (result) {
        if (result.error) {
          $(this).prop('disabled', false)
          $(this).removeClass('btn-secondary')
          $(this).addClass('btn-primary')
          $("#overlay").fadeOut(300);
        }
      });

You can verify whether this from your own overlay/disable by removing that treatment before calling confirmSubmit, too. Comment this out:
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
    $(this).addClass('btn-secondary')
    $(this).removeClass('btn-primary')
    $("#overlay").fadeIn(300);


It seems something breaks right after the "then()" method, because I'm able to log the result variable into the console, but trying to log anything right after the click event for the cardButton element doesn't work after the error

Right now using a debugger to see how it behaves inside the "then()" method

One interesting thing i noted is that it still verifies if the card number makes sense, it changes colours on the input if the card number is invalid (ex: 4242 4242 4242 4241) but still doesn't let me submit the form
